# How to deploy and Install Node.js and MongoDB application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, deployment, linode

I have purchase a server from https://www.linode.com. And I am able to set up an Ubuntu machine by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMEGih45sUQ) video

Now I have no clue how to deploy my Node.js application which is working in my local to the machine I have created

Basically I am looking for steps to install Node.js NPM express and MongoDB (I know the commands but not sure how to install on the machine I have created in linode)

Steps to deploy the Node.js application on the Ubuntu machine I have created

I have gone through [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/development/nodejs/Set-Up-and-Install-Nodejs) document (did not help much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below link.
you need to use nginx for routing your node application in the server(proxy server)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04